# How to map a Postgres Rails timestampz array with commas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, mapping, timestamp-with-timezone

The goal is to strip the date from the datetime from the data so multiple days can be overlayed  using Chartkick. The comma is interpreted by Ruby the break between fields. Rails and Chartkick have no problem presumably because they are 'timestamptz' datatype. Timestamp with Time Zone in PG.

```
day_one_array = [
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 00:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 0.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 01:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 0.0],
<snip>
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 21:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 0.0], 
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 22:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 0.0], 
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 23:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 0.0]]

puts day_one_array.each { |x| puts x }

parsing_daily_data.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected constant, expecting ']'
  [Thu, 28 Dec 2023 00:00:00.000000000 PST ...
```

Any suggestions how to handle this with Ruby or more directly in Rails. Working with timestampz data is challenging because the data gets reformatted depending on how it's looked at. In PGAdmin the same data appears as `'2022-12-05 08:00:00-08'`. And quotes come and go. Trying to convert back and forth from timestamp to strings is very challenging.

Comment: You're getting a syntax error since you have an array of strings but no quotes - Ruby does not have barewords. The entire question also hinges on the strange misconception that converting dates is hard (it's not) and is very likely an XY problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: "Working with timestampz data is challenging because the data gets reformatted depending on how it's looked at" - only if you rely on implicit string conversion. What you're dealing with is a classic problem called serialization where you need to convert records into a format that can be consumed on the front end.

Answer (score 1):

> Trying to convert back and forth from timestamp to strings is very challenging

In PostgreSQL, it's not; use [`to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#id-1.5.8.14.4.2.2.6.1.1.1) with a [format mask](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) on its way in: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tTWyIQ9-)

```sql
create table my_timestamptz (tstz timestamptz);

set timezone='PST8PDT';

insert into my_timestamptz
select to_timestamp('Thu, 28 Dec 2023 22:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 0.0',
                    'Dy, DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI:SS.US AAA TZH:TZM, AAA')
returning *;
```

| tstz |
| --- |
| 2023-12-28 22:00:00-08 |

Then [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#id-1.5.8.14.4.2.2.1.1.1.1) on its way out:

```sql
set timezone='PST8PDT';
select to_char(tstz,
               'Dy, DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI:SS.US TZ TZH:TZM, 0.0') 
from my_timestamptz;
```

| to_char |
| --- |
| Thu, 28 Dec 2023 22:00:00.000000 PST -08:00, 0.0 |

---

You can tamper with evidence directly:

```sql
set timezone='PST8PDT';
select to_char('today'::date + tstz::timetz,
               'Dy, DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI:SS.US TZ TZH:TZM, 0.0') 
from my_timestamptz;
```

| to_char |
| --- |
| Thu, 01 Feb 2024 22:00:00.000000 PST -08:00, 0.0 |

Or in the format pattern:

```sql
set timezone='PST8PDT';
select to_char(tstz,
               'Tue, 02 Feb 1999 HH24:MI:SS.US TZ TZH:TZM, 0.0') 
from my_timestamptz;
```

| to_char |
| --- |
| Tue, 02 Feb 1999 22:00:00.000000 PST -08:00, 0.0 |

Comment: Note that [PostgreSQL timestamp precision is 1μs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-TABLE), so you'll only keep 6 out of your 9 decimal places.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I, with another suggestion and one AI hint, did figure out how to do it in Rails.